# Lock_Row errors - Have you had to engineer fixes due to child record volumes? Data skew avoidance

Tags: account, data, data-skew

I'd be interested to hear of any solutions people had to create to overcome a high dependency on parent Accounts.

This article was written in 2012, so would be interested to hear of any updates to it, please? https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/04/avoid-account-data-skew-for-peak-performance.html

Comment: What issue are you facing? There are ways to avoid skews? what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The situation is there are c.55k active child records pointing at 1 account.  There are 300 agents working on c. 2k records that contain the active records.  They are regularly getting lock rows.  Past experience I have seen a process where a sequential account manager record created, every 10 k records.  I'm thinking my client is going to have to do the same to resolve this current situation.  I am also looking at the data, and seeing if it can be recategorised to lookup different account records instead.

Comment: if they are customer contacts person accounts could be a way. Each records is a account and a contact tied to the parent account. 1:1 model of tying 1 contact to 1 account would work depending on your use case.